# Not able to get responses from luis.ai to bot framework, getting error instead

Tags: botframework

I started working on bot framework in node.js and used luis.ai for my nlp.
Referring the documentation on azure for their botframework for node.js, I did the code changes in app.js. However I am getting the following error when running the code in online editor.

[info] Restarting server...
[info] Click on http://firstbot2-b893.azurewebsites.net to open your site
restify listening to http://undefined:undefined

Also, a new browser window opens with following error...

code    "ResourceNotFound"
message "/ does not exist"

Please find the app.js and package.json code below...

### app.js

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var botbuilder_azure = require("botbuilder-azure");

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata 
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var tableName = 'botdata';
var azureTableClient = new botbuilder_azure.AzureTableClient(tableName, process.env['AzureWebJobsStorage']);
var tableStorage = new botbuilder_azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, azureTableClient);

// Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user
//var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
// Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user
// This default message handler is invoked if the user's utterance doesn't
// match any intents handled by other dialogs.
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session, args) {
    session.send('You reached the default message handler. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
});
bot.set('storage', tableStorage);

// Make sure you add code to validate these fields
var luisAppId = process.env.LuisAppId;
var luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;
var luisAPIHostName = process.env.LuisAPIHostName || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '&subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;


// Main dialog with LUIS
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
// Add the recognizer to the bot
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })
.matches('Greeting', (session) => {
    session.send('You reached Greeting intent, you said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
})
.matches('Help', (session) => {
    session.send('You reached Help intent, you said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
})
.matches('Cancel', (session) => {
    session.send('You reached Cancel intent, you said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
})
.matches('Reports', (session) => {
    session.send('You reached Reports intent, you said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
})
.onDefault((session) => {
    session.send('Sorry, I did not understand \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
});

//bot.dialog('/', intents);
```

---

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "luisbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "^3.13.1",
    "botbuilder-azure": "^3.0.4",
    "restify": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "zip-folder": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason this is commented out:

```
//bot.dialog('/', intents);
```

Seems you need to define somewhere for dialog to listen, and matches up with the "/" no resource found error.

Comment: Yes, it gives the following error: Error: Dialog[/] already exists in library[*].

Answer (score 1):

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session, args) {
    session.send('You reached the default message handler. You said \'%s\'.', 
        session.message.text);
});
```

This second parameter counts as a root dialog (`'/'`), which is why you received the error message regarding the dialog already existing.

You're also plugging the `LuisRecognizer` into the `bot` level and then into an `IntentDialog`:

```
// Main dialog with LUIS
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
// Add the recognizer to the bot
bot.recognizer(recognizer);

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] })
```

You should only use one or the other, especially when starting off and when only using one created `LuisRecognizer`.

I recommend changing your `var bot` line to:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
```

And then using your `IntentDialog` only with your root dialog, by uncommenting this line:

```
//bot.dialog('/', intents);
```